# Firebase reg id for messagin isn't received on my phone,only on emulator

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send push notifications to my android app.The problem is that when i run the app at my phone i can't get the reg id.But when i run it on my emulator runs perfectly and gets the regid.Any ideas?In case needed here is the code

**MyFirebaseInstanceID.java**

```
@Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        super.onTokenRefresh();
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

        // Saving reg id to shared preferences
        storeRegIdInPref(refreshedToken);

        // sending reg id to your server
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);

        // Notify UI that registration has completed, so the progress indicator can be hidden.
        Intent registrationComplete = new Intent(Config.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE);
        registrationComplete.putExtra("token", refreshedToken);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(registrationComplete);
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(final String token) {
        // sending gcm token to server
        Log.e(TAG, "sendRegistrationToServer: " + token);
    }

    private void storeRegIdInPref(String token) {
        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putString("regId", token);
        editor.apply();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As according to Firebase [FirebaseInstanceIdService](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceIdService) is deprecated now.

You should try this to get Token !

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener( MyActivity.this,  new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
     @Override
     public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {          
           String newToken = instanceIdResult.getToken();    
     }
 });
```

Comment: Should i put this in my other class "MyFirebaseMessagingService" ? and delete the onTokenRefresh() in "MyFirebaseInstanceIDService"?

Comment: @AlexKolydas, you can put the above code in any of your activities `onCreate()` method.

Comment: you can use this in any `activity` or `fragment` to get Token. `MyFirebaseInstanceIDService` and its method `getToken()` are deprecated now.

Comment: I'm trying to put it on my activity's onCreate() but it cannot resolve "getInstanceId, InstanceIdResult and getToken for a strange reason...i've implemented the libraries of course...Will try to figure it out